# CSS3: Multiple rotated divs vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've three or more div and I want to rotate and align them vertically. I've tried but I didn't find a solution.

Css:

```
.rotation {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width:100px;
}
.rotation .container {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.rotation .rotate {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*IE 9*/
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*Chrome, Safari, Opera*/
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  background: #3c8d37;
  color: #fff;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="rotation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="rotate">First Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="rotate">Long Text Long Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="rotate">Very Long Text Very Long Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

The text length may vary with culture and I want to keep all div aligned. Is that possible? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't rotate the individual items...rotate the whole thing. Much simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're overthinking things.

Don't rotate the individual items...build it as you would a normal horizontal div and then rotate the parent. It also simplifies the mark-up

**HTML**

```
<div class="rotation">
    <div class="rotate">First Text</div>
    <div class="rotate">Long Text Long Text</div>
    <div class="rotate">Very Long Text Very Long Text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rotation {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.rotation .rotate {
    background: #3c8d37;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:arial;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:5px;
```

}

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7j1g8hha/2/)

Comment: This is cleaner than my code. Upvoted this, well done!

Comment: +1 Excellent and simple solution. Just one question, is the `display` setting on the `.rotation` required? Not sure if it is needed.

Comment: Not strictly, I just like having it no wider / taller than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. The trick is to put the rotation on the div `.rotation`. I also changed the `transform-origin` so that the rotation starts from the bottom left, instead of the middle.

```
.rotation {
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom 0;
    /*IE 9*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom 0;
    /*Chrome, Safari, Opera*/
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom 0;
}
.rotation:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.rotation .container {
    float: left;
}
.rotation .rotate {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #3c8d37;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:arial;
}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnazvthf/1/) for the result. Is this the way you wanted it?